# Can we add questions that explain some concept?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have seen some questions like: I'm looking for a resource that explains X, where X is a fairly broad, but not really broad subject.

Sometimes I really feel the urge to answer it with my own explanation. But then I'm not answering the question. Can I then post a new question with answer, explaining it?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean. I have difficulty understanding the second paragraph. Why would you not answer the question?

Comment: @quid The question is an (reference-request) question. I want to write an answer, explaining every bit of what a good resource would contain.

Comment: I see. I overlooked the "resource" in the first paragraph.

Comment: Is there any way you could provide a reference that you would recommend, *and also* give a "bonus" explanation?

Comment: This question about posting broad questions is itself quite broad. :)

Comment: You might have a look at older posts tagged ([meta-tag:self-answer]). Maybe you can find there some stuff relevant for your situation, too. (And if you consider this to be an important aspect of this post, you might also add the tag here.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and you definitely should! Stack Exchange has always encouraged self-answers. From the StackOverflow [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer):

> [...] Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.